# Connection timed out - when tried to access a website

Tags: router, dns

Current Scenario:

- Single PC  2 Networks -
- Broadband and Mobile network.

I can access a website (xyz.com) when I connect my PC to mobile network.
But I cannot access the same website when I connect using broadband network.
(With PC, cmd "Ping xyz.com" says "request timed out")

All website are working except this particular website works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This could be multiple issues. First off you could try changing your DNS servers. Typically, a broadband ISP will set your DHCP server to use their own DNS servers by default. Set your DNS server on your computer to google's public of 8.8.8.8 and see if that makes a difference.

Other than that it could be filtering, etc depending on what type of website it is.

Comment: `C:\Windows\system32>nslookup arobux.com
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    arobux.com
Address:  166.62.28.122`

Comment: @ManojShenoy can you try some other common websites such as google or apple and see what the nslookup command says for them?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JWS. Also, you can try to diagnose it yourself by doing the following on both networks:

- ping

  ping xyz.com

And checking the result.

- nslookup

  nslookup xyz.com
- dig / traceroute or tracert (Linux/Win respectively)

  dig xyz.com ANY

  tracert xyz.com

Comment: After setting DNS as 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 

`C:\Windows\system32>nslookup arobux.com
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    arobux.com
Address:  166.62.28.122`